# Typecast String to JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane

Is there a way to typecast `String` type to `JLayeredPane`? Following is the code I am using:

```
private static void build_tables() {  
    String sql="SELECT * FROM pos_tables WHERE pos_company_id='"
        +global_variables.company_id
        +"' AND shop_type='"
        +global_variables.shop_type
        +"'";  
    if(mysql_query.count_mysqls(variables.con.conn, sql)>0){  
        try {  
            ResultSet rs = mysql_query.execute_mysql(variables.con.conn, sql);  
            while (rs.next()) {  
                JLayeredPane JL = (JLayeredPane)rs.getObject("parent_floor");  
                tablesetup.addButton(rs.getString("table_name"),
                    Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("x")),
                    Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("y")), JL);    
            }  
        } catch (SQLException ex) {   
            Logger.getLogger(builder.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.swing.JLayeredPane
```

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JLayeredPane JL = (JLayeredPane)rs.getObject("parent_floor");
```

A database doesn't contain `JLayeredPane` objects. It contains a string.

What are you trying to do? Why are you using a `JLayeredPane`?

Just use a `JPanel`. Then you can create a `JLabel` using the string returned from the database query and then you add the label to the panel.

Something like:

```
String text = rs.getObject("parent_floor").toString();
JLabel label = new JLabel( text );
panel.add(label);
```

Comment: i am using tabbed pane and inside each tab i dynamically add buttons and labels(inside another layeredpane) Can this be done by just using JPanel ? can i add another Jpanel inside Jpanel ?

Comment: you can nest JPanels arbitrarily deep